# How did Leibniz's prototypes of a yaw system and a braking mechanism (for windmills) work?

Tags: engineering, leibniz

My question is concerned with two hardly mentioned yet very ingenious inventions of Leibniz. These two inventions represent technological inventiveness and visionary insight (about wind energy technology). My reference is [this website](http://www.gwlb.de/Leibniz/Leibnizarchiv/english/Leibniz_Life/windmill.htm).

A yaw system for the windmill is an automatic control mechanism that enables the windmill to capture maximum amount of wind energy by continuously turning the sails of mills to the direction of the wind (so the interaction with the wind will be maximal). A braking mechanism is a device that regulates the speed of the shaft to enable the wind to make mechanical work on the sails (by preventing the shaft from going into maximal speed).

My question is mainly about getting explanations. I didn't find any English website to explain those inventions of Leibniz, and I'll be glad to see one.

**Update**: I found a reference to those instruments of Leibniz in "The oxford handbook of Leibniz", page 538. The author of the handbook mentions an instrument called "**inventum memorabile**", "for the timely and regular braking of the wind shaft to avoid excessive damaging strain on the machinery resulting from excessively rapid rotation of the sails". The author also refers to the article "Leibniz' Inventum Memorabile: Die Konzeption einer Drehzahlregelung vom März 1686" by Hans Peter Munzenmayer. According to the abstract of the article, Leibniz's mechanism for speed regulation is in fact a feedback control system in the modern sense. Unfortunately, the article is in German, so I'm unable to read it.